# Spring suite tool. There were some strange barrel and question marks on the folder and file icons

Tags: java, spring, web

I don't undestand how those barrel and question marks affect to my maven web project. So can anybody help to clean up this mess? These marks look like on the picture below:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfZ7G.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are just indicators to help you see quickly which files are managed in a repository. The barrel indicates that the file is in sync with your repository, question mark indicates a new file that hasn't been comitted to a repository yet and a little star means you altered a file locally and haven't committed the changes yet.

Comment: I was going crazy by that. Thought it was some kind of hidden warning.